# print to cout from embedded python

Tags: c++, python, printing, embedded, cout

I am using python's [very high level layer](http://docs.python.org/c-api/veryhigh.html) to embed some python code to a commercial application that supports a proprietary scripting language.
The problem is that the application itself is coded in C++ and it has a embedded log window which displays cout and cerr. I was wondering if there is a way to print to cout/cerr from python... I already goggled a lot about it, but I cannot find a simple way to do it.

Thanks!

Comment: Hm, what about `print`? Am I missing something?

Comment: print goes to stdout and stderr I *need* it to go to cout and cerr.

Comment: It depends on how the C++ application captures the output... If it reassigned the actual low-level file-handles then `print` in Python will work, otherwise you might have to make special Python functions to be called instead of `print`.

Comment: Any idea how this special functions would be? Print simply does not work I tried it already...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no simple way. The application itself must assign file-likes to `sys.stdout` and `sys.stderr` in order to capture them.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using these calls:

```
import sys
sys.stderr.write('blah blah\n')
sys.stdout.write('blah blah\n')
```

or alternatively using these ones:

```
print >> sys.stderr, 'blah blah'
print >> sys.stdout, 'blah blah'
```